# How do I install caps2esc?

Tags: shortcut-keys, systemd, capslock

I am switching back from mac-land, and the thing that bugs me the most about linux these days is the keybindings. Specifically, right now, I miss Karabiner, and the ability to turn the caps lock both into control and escape at the sametime.

Luckily, I found caps2esc. Unluckily, I don't quite understand how to install it.

I found the way to compile and `make install` both interception tools and caps2esc. But now it seems I need to mess around with systemd? Now I'm lost.

Help?

Here's the relevant documentation:

1. https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/caps2esc
2. https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/tools/blob/master/README.md

Comment: to really help I'd have to run it, and sorry i'm not doing that. a quick scan-read of files however and I don't see the need of sysd except if you want it to auto-run every boot or use system (systemctl) commands to stop/restart/start/.. it (which would be nicer yes) but are not necessary from my read.

Answer (score 17):

I think I mostly figured this out.

1. Follow the instructions to `cmake`, `make`, `sudo make install`
2. On Ubuntu/Debian, these executables are now in `/usr/local/bin/caps2esc`
3. `sudoedit /etc/udevmon.yaml` and then put this in:

   ```
    - JOB: "intercept -g $DEVNODE | caps2esc | uinput -d $DEVNODE"
      DEVICE:
        EVENTS:
          EV_KEY: [KEY_CAPSLOCK, KEY_ESC]
   ```
4. `sudoedit /etc/systemd/system/udevmon.service` and put this in:

   ```
    [Unit]
    Description=udevmon
    Wants=systemd-udev-settle.service
    After=systemd-udev-settle.service

    [Service]
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/nice -n -20 /usr/local/bin/udevmon -c /etc/udevmon.yaml

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
5. `sudo systemctl enable --now udevmon`

Comment: When I ran `sudo make install` on interception tools, it installed `udevmon` to `/usr/local/bin/udevmon`. I changed the reference in `/etc/systemd/system/udevmon.service` from `/usr/bin/udevmon` to `/usr/local/bin/udevmon` and all was well.

Comment: Also note that if you don't already have it ( didn't on Pop!_OS), you'll need to install Interception Tools: https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/tools. The `cmake ..`, `make`, `sudo make install` instructions worked out for that for me as well.

Comment: update to add:  I also had to install `libyaml-cpp-dev` and `libevdev` to install interception tools.

Comment: I've also had to install `libevdev-dev`, otherwise I was getting a `interception_tools/uinput.cpp:14:38: fatal error: libevdev/libevdev-uinput.h: No such file or directory`.

Comment: To recap from the message and comments (any my own experience): 1. `sudo apt install libyaml-cpp-dev libevdev-dev libudev-dev`. 2. Compile and interception-tools following @Tom comment. 3. Install [caps2esc](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/caps2esc) (`mkdir build`, `cd build`, `cmake .. `, `make`, `sudo make install`). 4. Create the files `/etc/udevmon.yaml` and  `/etc/systemd/system/udevmon.service` as explained above BUT use the path `/usr/local/bin/udevmon`  instead of `/usr/bin/udevmon`. 5. `sudo systemctl enable --now udevmon`.

Comment: The project already provides simpler Ubuntu instructions and a link to a PPA.

Answer (score 1):

I've lightly adapted a guide to installing the sister application `dual-function-keys` on this [page](https://emacsredux.com/blog/2020/07/05/remap-enter-to-control-in-gnu-linux-2020-edition/). I managed to follow the steps in the OP's answer and the comments with some trial and erorr, but this guide puts it all together in order.

```
# install build deps
$ sudo apt install libudev-dev libyaml-cpp-dev libevdev-dev cmake
# create a folder where to clone the source code
$ mkdir src && cd src
# clone the necessary code
$ git clone https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/tools
$ git clone https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/caps2esc
# build and install the interception framework
$ cd tools
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ cd ../..
# build the caps2esc plugin
$ cd caps2esc
$ make && sudo make install
```

After the installation make and edit the two configuration files as in the OP's answer, changing the path to the install location if necessary.